# Traversing Data Type with Recursive Binary Tree List in Function

Tags: haskell

I created a recursive binary tree where there can be unlimited children:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a
            | Node [Tree a]
```

My issue is in the syntax during the creation of a function in order to traverse the tree.

Say I want to do something easy, like give an argument 1 and then find out `Bool` if 1 occurs within the tree. I'm having issue with the function definition when the `Node` is `[Tree a]` instead of `Node [Leaf root Leaf]`. I'm not used to the function calling a list in the variable.

Here's how it would work with a simpler recursive data type:

```
occs :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Bool 
occs x (Leaf y) = x == y
occs x (Node left y right) = x == y || occs x left || occs x right
```

However, `(Node left y right)` are no longer proper because `Node` is now a listed tree `[Tree a]`. How can you write a listed tree `[Tree a]` as a variable to manipulate?

The expected results would be `True` or `False` if it appears but the issue is mainly in the syntax of identifying a listed `[Tree a]` in the function. I've tried multiple ways of writing it and it always comes back error.

Comment: We can't help you understand what went wrong with your attempt if you won't show us your attempt. So include the code you think ought to work but doesn't, along with the error message you get.

Comment: In `Leaf y` you are [pattern matching](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) the `Leaf a` constructor. Valid matches for your `Node [Tree a]` constructor are: `Node _`, `Node []`, `Node [x]` (or `Node (x:[])`), `Node [x,y]` (or `Node (x:y:[])`), and so on.

Comment: What is the definition of `example4`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to recursively check if any of the branches (that's what I'm calling the trees in the list) contains `x`. Luckily the Prelude includes a function [any](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any) to make this very easy:

```
occs :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Bool 
occs x (Leaf y) = x == y
occs x (Node branches) = any (occs x) branches
```

(`any` is also very easy to implement oneself if you wanted to)

Comment: So you can name it whatever you'd like and it just represents the list. But one final question: how do I create an example to test.

      `example :: Tree a
      example = Node [(Leaf 1) (Leaf 7) (Leaf 8)]`

Comment: that looks fine, although the type is `Tree a Int` (any numeric type would do in place of `Int`, but it doesn't actually matter).

Comment: Also, what do you mean I can implement `any` if I wanted. Could it be defined instead of calling the library function?

Comment: Yes, all I was trying to say that it isn't some "magical" function provided for us by the standard library - like most library functions, it's there for convenience but could easily be implemented in a few lines of Haskell if you needed to. Since it is provided for us, then you never need to actually write it yourself, except as an exercise.

Comment: Could you please show me? It would be extremely helpful to understand the function. Thank you so much for helping me btw! The answer was obvious once I saw it but writing examples to test it caused me some time.

Comment: there's not space in a comment to do it, certainly not to lay it out properly - but I would strongly encourage you to try it out yourself, but here are some large hints. It's a very simple recursive function: the base case is `any p [] = False`, the recursive case is `any p (x:xs)`, you need to test if `p x` is true or false and give the appropriate result (one involves a recursive call to `any p xs`, the other can give an answer straightaway).

Comment: I created a function to match it but it doesn't work in the actual function where `any` was used. 

`helper p [] = False
helper p (x:xs)
  | p == x    = True
  | otherwise = helper p xs`

Comment: No, it won't. Think about it logically. You want to tell if any element in the list satisfies `p`. So you test `p` against the first element: if it passes, do you need to examine the rest of the list? If it fails, do you want to give an immediate answer of "no"? That's what your function above does.

Comment: So I wrote this new one and it compiles but when I test it by example it gives me an error. The code: `helper p []   = False
helper p (x : xs)
  | p x       = True
  | otherwise = helper p xs`

Comment: `* No instance for (Eq (Tree2 Int)) arising from a use of `occs * In the expression: occs example5`
      `In an equation for `it: it = occs example5`

Comment: I put the full code up. It won't test an example but it compiles. I'm not sure what the error message above means.

Comment: @Drake From your error, it looks like you have an `example5` which I assume is a tree, and you're calling `occs example5` to run the test. But `occs` takes two arguments, not one. It should be e.g. `occs 7 example5`.

Comment: DUHHHHH! I'm such an idiot, you're totally right. I've been focused on the code so much I forgot what it was doing. Thank you all so much, you've all been amazing

Answer (score 0):

Since Robin Zigmond gave an answer to your question, "How can you write a listed tree `[Tree a]` as a variable to manipulate?", I'll try to answer differently.

> I created a recursive binary tree where there can be unlimited children:
>
> ```
> data Tree a = [...]
> ```

Then it isn't binary but *n*-ary.

This exact type already exists in the `containers` package under the [`Data.Tree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Tree.html) module.

`Data.Tree` has a bunch of type class instances defined for it, and one of those is [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable), and the function you're writing is already in `Data.Foldable` under the name [`elem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:elem) and has the type:

```
elem :: (Eq a, Foldable t) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

So if your choice of data type is an *n*-ary tree, `Data.Tree` and `elem` would be the right choices.

---

If, on the other hand, an actual binary tree with two child nodes is what you're after, defining this and making it an instance of `Foldable` would give you `elem` in the same way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data BinaryTree a
  = Leaf
  | Node a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)
  deriving (Foldable)

-- now `elem` comes for free
```

**Edit:** Following amalloy's suggestion, the `Foldable` instance was derived instead.

But because `elem` is only constrained with `Eq a` and not `Ord a`, you cannot get *O(log n)* lookups as you would be able to for a binary *search* tree, so you'd have to call it something else if you wanted that:

```
occs :: Ord a => a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool
occs _ Leaf = False
occs x (Node y left right) =
  case x `compare` y of
    LT -> occs x left
    EQ -> True
    GT -> occs x right
```

Comment: Writing Foldable instances by hand gets tiresome quickly. Instead, derive them with DeriveFoldable.